# realVNC Server is running, why can't I find it listening on *any* port?

Tags: firewall, vnc

Windows 10 Home Version 22H2, newly installed. I downloaded real VNC Server 7.5.1 (r50075) x64, with free personal use license. I run it as Administrator (but UAC pops up asking for permission anyway). It looks fine on this machine and gets a green checkmark in the upper right corner of the GUI.

But when I try to connect from realVNC on my phone, I get a timeout. The phone works fine connecting to another Win10 machine running a *much* older version of VNC, 5.1.1 (r117550) x64). On that machine running the ancient VNC, I can run `netstat -ano | find "LISTEN" | find "5900"` and see that there is a process listening on port 5900, and as expected, tasklist shows that the process is vncserver.exe.

But with the newer version of VNC server, netstat doesn't show anything listening on port 5900, or anything close. Here is a screenshot showing the green checkmark in VNC Server, task manager with VNC SERVER running, and a cmd window with the output of `netstat -ano`[image: screenshot]

Googling suggests that Windows Firewall is the likely culprit, but I don`t think a firewall could prevent the program from listening. And in any case, I got the same behavior with the firewall turned off. And to top that off, the Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security app Inbound Rules shows two entries for VNC Server, one for  TCP and the other for UDP, both allowing any interface, any port, and any user.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

===***EDIT*** ***More info***===
As I noted in a comment, the parameters are pretty much all at their default values, in particular, localhost is false, ipListenAddresses is empty (meaning listen on all addresses), ip ListendProtocols is TCP,UDP, and RfbPort is 5900. And I've turned off Windows Defender Firewall. So, in this state, I went to Options->Troubleshooting and selected "Create a debug log file". And this is the contents of that file:

```
    RealVNC(R) Server 7.5.1 (r50075) x64 (May 30 2023 13:07:39)
Copyright (C) RealVNC Ltd.
RealVNC and VNC are trademarks of RealVNC Ltd and are protected by trademark
registrations and/or pending trademark applications in the European Union,
United States of America and other jurisdictions.
Protected by UK patent 2481870; US patent 8760366; EU patent 2652951.
See https://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
For third party acknowledgements see:
https://www.realvnc.com/docs/7/foss.html
OS: Microsoft Windows 10, version 22H2, x64
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.794Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: LogDestMem: Start replaying stored messages
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.794Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Localize: Locales en_US
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.794Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: JoinMgr: Getting CloudConfig.pkg from built-in resource
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.794Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: JoinMgr: Using business identifier 21d22e22-eeb1-47dd-955f-00ca74f34f1e
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.794Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Licensing: Using online license token 1, changed 1
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.794Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: LogDestMem: Finished replaying stored messages
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.794Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: main: Running service-mode server
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.794Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Service: Service dispatcher starting
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.799Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Service: set status to START_PENDING(2) [seq# 1]
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.799Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Service: set status to RUNNING(4) [seq# 2]
<13> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.840Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: ServerManager: Server started
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.899Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Configuration: Authentication=VncAuth (Preference)
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.899Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Configuration: EnableAnalytics=1 (Preference)
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.899Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Configuration: EnableAutoUpdateChecks=1 (Preference)
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.899Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Configuration: Password=<binary> (Preference)
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.901Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: AgentMgrService: sessionChange: 1 1
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.919Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: SModuleCloudAccess: Beginning listening as [9uJFVm-UVbbB-JCBXYb]
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.937Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: HostedRegion: Using region USEast
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.939Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: SModuleRsaKey: Using new key: 5b-c9-9d-1b-7a-61-0d-8d (catchphrase "Brazil Linda control. Egypt Cecilia forward.")
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:18.950Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: SModuleCtrlCommsListen: listening on RealVNC.vncservice.vncserver.CtrlComms
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:19.090Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: SDesktopAgent: agent connected
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:19.090Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: UiProcess: Restart in 500ms
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:19.098Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: ServerApp: Input desktop is now 'Default'
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:19.098Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Agent: Localize: Locales en_US
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:19.098Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Agent: AgentAppWin: Starting
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:19.098Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Agent: EndSessionNotifier: Cannot listen for logoff events (console is attached)
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:19.315Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: CtrlComms: connected: <namedpipe-server-RealVNC.vncservice.vncserver.CtrlComms-0000000000000388>
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:19.558Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: HostedRendezvous: Using Rendezvous service at https://hc-8-us-va-1.services.vnc.com/rendezvous
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:20.090Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: UiProcess: UI process started
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:32.562Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Licensing: Using online license token 1, changed 0
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:33.186Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: ServerApp: Input desktop is now 'Winlogon'
<14> 2023-06-20T19:32:35.956Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: ServerApp: Input desktop is now 'Default'
<14> 2023-06-20T19:35:49.214Z DESKTOP-NP7LJEH vncserver[1556]: Licensing: Using online license token 1, changed 0
```

The string 5900 does not appear in it at all. And there are only three occurrences of the string "listen":

```
SModuleCloudAccess: Beginning listening as [9uJFVm-UVbbB-JCBXYb]
SModuleCtrlCommsListen: listening on RealVNC.vncservice.vncserver.CtrlComms
Agent: EndSessionNotifier: Cannot listen for logoff events (console is attached)
```

Can anyone see anything in the log that might explain what's going on?

Comment: Is RealVNC licensed? If yes, have you tried reinstalling RealVNC?

Comment: "but I don`t think a firewall could prevent the program from listening." on the contrary. If a program tries to open a port for listening, the Windows firewall opens and asks the user if he wants to allow this action. On the other hand, connecting to outside servers (what programs who do for example some sort of homephoning) doesn’t trigger the Windows firewall. I’m talking about the default FW settings.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I got the "free for personal use" license. I guess I'll try reinstalling, as I don't exactly remember any license key dialogue. BTW, in case it could make a difference, Windows 10 is not activated, I just installed it using the Media Creation Tool.

Comment: @Ro-ee Yeah, but what VNC Server is supposed to do is listen on port  5900 for incoming connections with either TCP or UDP protocols. And netstat does not show any such listening even with the firewall completely turned off. And when it's not turned off, it has entries allowing VNC Server to listen for both TCP and UDP connections on any port and any interface from any user. That's what convinces me the firewall is not preventing VNC Server from listening, as it does on the other machine running an old version.

Comment: @harrymc I just removed it and reinstalled it. No change in behavior. This is the "Lite" version, which is free for personal use. You have to be logged in to a realVNC account to download it, and the license is part of the installation process, there is no separate license key. This is what the "Licensing" tab in the server's GUI says: Lite
Subscription model: Per Device
Valid for: 3 desktops
License source: Online
Features
256-bit AES encryption
Cloud connectivity
VNC authentication

Comment: What are the [parameters](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002251297-VNC-Server-Parameter-Reference-) of the RealVNC server? Some parameters, such as `localhost`, may cause it to only accept connections from the local computer. The syntax might be similar to `vncserver -localhost no` (I'm not a RealVNC user). There might also exist a `vnc.conf` settings file somewhere.

Comment: @harrymc Great find, the documentation for server parameters! But alas, they are all at their default values, which includes localhost false, ipListenAdresses empty (meaning listen on all addresses), ipListenProtocols TCP,UDP. And RfbPort is 5900. And Windows firewall is turned off. I'm at wits end.

Comment: @harrymc I updated the question with the contents of its debug log file. I don't see any clue in it - it doesn't mention 5900 or "listen" in any way meaningful to me...

Comment: Some of [this advice](https://www.anyviewer.com/how-to/vnc-server-is-not-currently-listening-for-cloud-connections-2578.html) may be pertinent.